# Distinguish between imported and globally defined module attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, attributes, inspect

How to distinguish between attributes defined at global level and those imported from other modules programatically? For instance, I want to know which module `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` and `MY_HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` defined in mymod.py belong to.

Contents of `mymod.py`:

```
from pickle import HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

MY_HIGHEST_PROTOCOL = 123
```

Inspecting in `IPython`.

```
In [2]: import mymod

In [3]: dir(mymod)
Out[3]:
['HIGHEST_PROTOCOL',
 'MY_HIGHEST_PROTOCOL',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__']
```

Comment: What's the actual *problem* you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to list all the attributes defined in a module.

Comment: Could you keep going down [another four whys](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_whys)?

Comment: The use case is to document all atributes present in a module. Currently system just ignores such attributes which is bad. Alternative is to document all these attributes in all the modules. This will result in redundancy. Hence the question. P.S.- Good to know about the 'whys'.